# Стандартный ввод в C++

Tags: c++

Из стандартного потока необходимо считать две переменных: int и string. Ввод разделен символом конца строки, переменная string возможно содержит пробелы. Хотелось бы избежать неуклюжего кода вида:

```
int i;
string s;
cin >> i;
//перед считыванием строки приходится хавать символ конца строки
cin.get();
//считываем строку полностью (возможно, сторока содержит пробелы)
getline(cin, s);
```

Хотелось бы решить элегантно, типа:

```
int i;
string s;
cin >> i >> s;
```

но, видимо, перед этим как-то нужно настроить объект cin.
Подскажите как сделать красиво, scanf не приветствуется.

Answer (score 3):

Можно, к примеру, такую конструкцию организовать

```
int i;
string s;
getline((cin >> i).ignore(100, '\n'), s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a;
char b[10];

cin>>a>>b;
cout<<"int a:"<<a<<"char b:"<<b;
```

cin & cout  не хотят работать с string, поэтому можно считывать в char а потом преобразовать в string.

Comment: Хочу выжать таки что то из cin, либо проиграться и итераторами потоков ввода.